# max-width doesn't work on img on firefox

Tags: html, css, image, firefox

I'm making a website (http://emosistemas.com/web/) but I have problem with "max-width" in the images.

In google chrome it works fine, but, in firefox (in responsive mode) it doesn't resize it.

The images that fails are:

- the image under "Inicio"
- the 3 images under "Inicio" image

In responsive mobile (less than 500px aprox), the last 3 images works fine because have "width:100%".

I try to transform into block, inline-block, position relative, specify widht:auto... but any works.

I'm using Firefox 41.0 and the last nightly version.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Full screen (works ok): https://i.stack.imgur.com/XinAq.jpg

Responsive mode (the images don't resize it): https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEVKG.jpg

Comment: It's not really clear what images you're talking about, please be more specific and post some code.

Comment: Add code to show us what you have tried yourself so far.

Comment: Sorry, images added

My only css is "max-width" in the images...

Comment: in firefox, around 857 screen width, your 3 images has exceed your container

Comment: I saw multiple container exceed html, body container....asaik...which leads to a more bigger problem...and thats the furthest i will go...

Comment: Yes, this is the problem, if you try it in google chrome it works fine
The problem seems to be "max-width", I'm not sure if is a firefox bug or similar with <img>

Comment: So if I understand this, you have set your image to a width of 100% and a max-width of 100%? Please provide more detail.

Comment: No, I put "max-width:100%", the "width:100%" is only for less than 450px, so the problem is the "max-width"...